# Is it possible to do configure-make-make install?

Tags: go, makefile, gnu-make, cgo

I have some Go source files: one.go, two.go,main.go

I build them to C static library for using in my cross-platform application compilation.

There are 4 types of application compilation:

1. Compilation on Windows
2. Compilation on Ubuntu
3. Compilation on Mac
4. Cross-compilation for Windows from Ubuntu

For 1,2,3 I use:

```
go build -buildmode c-archive -o libxyz.a .
```

For 4, I use:

```
GOOS="windows" GOARCH="amd64" CGO_ENABLED="1" CXX="x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++" CC="x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" go build -buildmode c-archive -o libxyz.a .
```

Is it somehow possible to do that by the configure-make-make install procedure?
(There is no configure.ac file in the xyz Go source package)

Also, it possible to use pkg-config in that?

Comment: Of course it's possible. There's nothing stopping you from writing your configure-make-install configuration as you wish. But it's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to do that by the configure-make-make install procedure [?]

Yes.

Should you do it, is this easy, is this sensible, does this provide any benefit? No, no, no, no.

If you want to type less: Write a small shell script (or a tiny Makefile if you *insist* on using make for whatever reason).

Comment: Ok, understood that. Thanks